# generic JQuery statement to manipulate many direct child elements

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to use jquery to hide a DIV while mousing over the DIV and show another DIV instead, similar to hover effect.

My code selects all DIVs at once, but I want only the DIV over which the mouse is over to be selected. How can I do this?

I assigned unique CSS IDs to the DIVs and duplicated the corresponding jQuery code and adapted the code to these CSS IDs.

But that would mean that I would have to duplicate the jQuery code 10 times for 10 different DIVs.

```
<div class="swapcontainer swaps3 nospacebetween contentpadding1 bgcolorred">
  <div class="swapsubcontainer swap1">
    <div id="div1a" class="swap first" style="display:block;">
      <div class="swappadding1">
        <p>text1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div1b" class="swap second" style="display:none;" >
      <div class="swappadding1">
        <p>text2</p>
        <a href="/">link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swapsubcontainer swap2">
    <div id="div1a" class="swap first" style="display:block;">
      <div class="swappadding1">
        <p>text1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div1b" class="swap second" style="display:none;" >
      <div class="swappadding1">
        <p>text2</p>
        <a href="/">link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").children(".first").css("display", "none");
    jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").children(".second").css("display", "block");
  });
  jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").children(".first").css("display", "block");
    jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").children(".second").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ander9023/dwcfgqp5/

How can I change the jQuery code so that it can be used generically for any number of these DIVs, but only works on the DIV over which the mouse is currently positioned?

Comment: Use the `this` in the event listener, or pass in the `e`vent and then `e.target` is the element that the event originated from.  Ref. [Event Basics](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change jQuery(".swapsubcontainer") to $(this)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).children(".first").css("display", "none");
      $(this).children(".second").css("display", "block");
   });
   jQuery(".swapsubcontainer").mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).children(".first").css("display", "block");
      $(this).children(".second").css("display", "none");
   });
});
```